# Symfony 2 - Home page routing

Tags: php, symfony

I want to do a route for home page, so if it is / or /index or /index.php send to same controller(to Index controller)

So i wrote this

```
homepage:
    pattern:  /
    defaults: { _controller: DprocMainBundle:Index:index}
homepage_1:
    pattern:  /index
    defaults: { _controller: DprocMainBundle:Index:index}
homepage_2:
    pattern:  /index.php
    defaults: { _controller: DprocMainBundle:Index:index}
```

It works, but its duplicate.. How i can do multiple route at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use optional parts in your routing:

```
homepage:
    pattern: /{name}.{ext}
    defaults:
       _controller: ...
       name: index
       ext: php
    requirements:
       ext: php
       name: index
```

> **SIDEBAR**: In the future, there will be better support for optional placeholders: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/5424