# How to set Home page route in Symfony 2.8

Tags: php, symfony, routes

I got a hard time learning `Symfony 2.8`.

I have created a `bundle` called `BlogBudle` and inside this I created a `controller` called `HomeController`.

My goal is:
Create a `/test` `URL` and assign it to `home page url`

**Below is my code:**

**/var/www/symfony/app/config/routing.yml**

```
blog:
resource: "@BlogBundle/Controller/"
type:     annotation
prefix:   /

app:
resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
type:     annotation
```

**/var/www/symfony/src/BlogBundle/Controller/HomeController.php**

```
namespace BlogBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;

class HomeController extends Controller
{

  /**
   * @Route("/test")
   */

  public function indexAction()
  {
      return $this->render('BlogBundle:Default:index.html.twig');
   }
 }
```

When I run `php app/console debug:router`, it shows

> Name                       Method   Scheme   Host   Path
>
> blog_home_index            ANY      ANY      ANY    /test

**Problem:**
If I visit `http://www.example.com/test`, it's showing `404` error.

**Also below is my VH Configuration:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  #ServerAdmin admin@test.com
  ServerName mysmfony.com
  ServerAlias www.mysymfony.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/symfony/web
  DirectoryIndex app_dev.php

  <Directory /var/www/symfony/web>
      AllowOverride All
      Options All
   </Directory>

   ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mysymfony.com.log
   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mysymfony.com.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony 2 - Home page routing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19156417/symfony-2-home-page-routing)

Comment: it's symfony as homepage is showing Symfony welcome page

Comment: `http://www.example.com/test` did you see [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/_images/errors-in-prod-environment.png) error?

Comment: yes ,it was the error

Comment: what's the output of `php app/console debug:router --env=prod`?

Comment: `blog_home_index   ANY      ANY      ANY    /test`

Comment: if you go to `http://www.example.com/app_dev.php/test` did you see the page?

Comment: it's showing like `You are not allowed to access this file. Check app_dev.php for more information.`

Answer (score 2):

Need to overwrite your bundle route in **app/config/routing.yml** such as :

```
user_test:
    resource: "@BlogBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /
```

and

Here is route for redirect to your Home page

**BlogBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml**

```
any_unique_route_name:
    pattern:  /test
    defaults: { _controller: BlogBundle:Home:index }
```

Make sure this is helpful to you.

Comment: I had same issue. Thanks @KishanPatel

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example :

routing.yml

```
my_route_name:
    path:      /test
    defaults:
        _controller: NamespaceBlogBundle:Home:index
```

Also if your controller is called HomeController render should be like this

```
public function indexAction()
  {
      return $this->render('NamespaceBlogBundle:Home:index.html.twig');
   }
```

[Symfony routing doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html)

Comment: not working :( .Also doc example is on `App Bundle` whereas my problems occur my own bundle.

Comment: in app/config/routing.yml add your path to routing.yml that is in your bundle and add the code i gave you in the routing.yml file of your bundle